# Angular 6 - http.get not launched

Tags: angular, http, promise, get

I training on PrimeNG and created a service to get data from a json file.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable

But impossible to get json data.

The method is called from a component using :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.nodeService.getFileSystem().then(files => this.files = files);
}
```

I'm using this method in the service :

```
private filesystemUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/data/filesystem.json';  

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getFileSystem() {
  return this.http.get(this.filesystemUrl)
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => <TreeNode[]> res);
}
```

The console shows :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object:
>   {"body":{"error":"Collection 'data' not
>   found"},"url":"http://localhost:4200/assets/data/filesystem.json","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not
>   Found"}
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
>       at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:500)
>       at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)

If I click in the console message on "url":"http://localhost:4200/assets/data/filesystem.json" I can access the json file so it should be another problem.
This file is located in "assets/data/filesystem.json", and I modified angular.json :

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  "src/assets/data"
]
```

**The main strange is that in network tab in the browser, I don't see any get call that try to access this json file :**

```
localhost   304 document    vendor.js:100488    210 B   304 ms  
runtime.js  304 script  (index) 211 B   4 ms    
polyfills.js    304 script  (index) 212 B   6 ms    
styles.js   304 script  (index) 212 B   7 ms    
vendor.js   304 script  (index) 213 B   17 ms   
main.js 304 script  (index) 212 B   17 ms   
info?t=1539698839604    200 xhr zone.js:2969    367 B   2 ms    
websocket   101 websocket   sockjs.js:1683  0 B Pending
```

I've tried other ways to write my method, like this one that seems ok in my IDE :

```
getFileSystem() {
  return this.http.get(this.filesystemUrl)
  .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
    console.log(response.json());
    return response.json();
  }))
  .subscribe();
}
```

but then, in component method calling the service, I didn't find a way to change "then()" because : [ts] Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.

I'v also tried the service method like this, withoud errors shown in IDE for service or component, it sould be ok :

```
getFileSystem() {
  return this.http.get<TreeNode[]>(this.filesystemUrl);
}
```

But result in console :

> ERROR  {body: {…}, url:
>   "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/filesystem.json", headers:
>   HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"} body: {error:
>   "Collection 'data' not found"} headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames:
>   Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} status: 404 statusText: "Not
>   Found" url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/filesystem.json"
>   **proto**: Object

If anyone can help ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Create your service like this:

```
    private filesystemUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/data/filesystem.json';  

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getFileSystem(): Observable<TreeNode[]> {
  return this.http.get<TreeNode[]>(this.filesystemUrl);

}
```

You are returning an Observable and you must subscribe to it in your component:

```
private treeNode: TreeNode[];
ngOnInit() {
  this.nodeService.getFileSystem().subscribe(data => {
     this.treeNode=data;
     console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I now get error in console : {body: {…}, url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/filesystem.json", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}